# Кодирование слов

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

Здравствуйте. Тренируюсь в с++ (не чистый), пишу программу. Должна переводить слова в цифры(причём a-1, b-2, z-26, aa-27...) и обратно. В одну сторону работает отлично, а в другую багует на любом сочетании цифр, при переводе которых в буквы присутствует буква z. В чём ошибка и как её можно исправить?

```
/* Numerically Speaking */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Big{
    int len;
    int num[50];
};

Big number;
Big letter;

Big sumn(Big *a, int n, int base)
{
      Big res = *a;
      int pos=0;
      int i=0;
      res.num[pos]+=n;
      for(i=0; i<=res.len; i++)
      {
         if(res.num[i]>base)
          {         
            res.num[i+1]+=res.num[i]/base;
            res.num[i]%=base;
          }
      }  
      if (res.num[res.len]>0) res.len++;
      return res;
}

Big multi(Big *a, int b, int base)
{
  Big res=*a; 
  int r = 0, i;
  for (i=0;i<res.len || r != 0;i++)
  {
    res.num[i] = res.num[i] * b + r;
    r = res.num[i]/base;
    res.num[i]%=base;
  }
     if (i > res.len)
    res.len = i;
  return res;
}

void let2num()
{
    for(int i=letter.len-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        number=multi(&number, 26, 10);
        number=sumn(&number, letter.num[i],10);
        number=multi(&number, 1, 10);
    }
}

void num2let() 
{
    for(int i=number.len-1; i>=0; i--) 
    {
        letter=multi(&letter, 10, 26);
        letter=sumn(&letter, number.num[i], 26);
    }
}


int main() 
{
    char buf[1024];
    int x;

    while(scanf("%s", buf)==1)
    {
        if (!strcmp(buf, "*")) break;
        if (buf[0]>='0' && buf[0]<='9')
        {
            number.len = strlen(buf);
            for(int i=0; i<number.len; i++) 
            {
                number.num[i] = buf[number.len-i-1]-'0';
            }
            num2let();
        }
        else
        {
            letter.len = strlen(buf);
            for(int i=0; i<letter.len; i++)
            {
                letter.num[i] = buf[letter.len-i-1]-'a'+1;
            }
            number.len = 1;
            let2num();
        }


        for(int i=letter.len-1; i>=0; i--) 
                {
                    printf("%c", ('a'+letter.num[i])-1);
                }
        printf("\t");
        for(int i=number.len-1; i>=0; i--) 
            {
                printf("%c", '0'+number.num[i]);
                if (i && (i%3==0)) 
                {
                    printf(",");
                }
            }
        printf("\n");
        memset(&number, 0, sizeof(Big));
        memset(&letter, 0, sizeof(Big));


    }
}
```

Comment: А вы пробовали пройти вашу программу под отладчиком? Почему? В visual studio встроен прекрасный отладчик.

Comment: Естественно пробовал. И не раз. Но никак не могу понять, почему именно не хочет оставаться значение буквы "z"-26.

Comment: у меня при z выводит 26. Можете привести пример ввода, вывода и ожидаемого правильно вывода?

Кстати, у Вас никакой не с++. А почти чистый си (из с++ используется только то, что можно в цикле писать `for(int i` и не писать `struct` при объявлении переменных).

Comment: Любое кол-во z больше 2. 18278(zzz), 702(zz)и так далее, а также 35779(azxc) и похожие.

Comment: Отлично, если вы отлаживали, в какой строке вычисленное значение не то, которое вы ожидаете? Чему равны в той же строке остальные переменные?

(Кстати: http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего в этой строке зря прибавляете единицу:

```
letter.num[i] = buf[letter.len-i-1]-'a'+1;
```

Косвенно это подтверждается тем, что программа выдает неправильный числовой результат. Легко подсчитать, что zz должно быть эквивалентно 676 (25 * 26 + 25), а у вас получается 702 (26 * 26 + 26). У Вас буквы - это, фактически, цифры в 26-ричной системе счисления. Очевидно, они должны быть в диапазоне от 0 до 25. Если же Вы хотите, чтобы результирующие числа начинались с единицы (a = 1, aa = 27), то единицу надо прибавлять к результату.